# Angular2 ng-content scss nested styles and StyleUrls not working when using :host

Tags: angular, sass, angular2-ngcontent

I am building a component which uses `ng-content` and I have found that I cannot use nested scss or the StylesUrl when I use the `:host >>>`

For instance :

```
:host >>> .toolbar-brand{
  color: red;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

:host >>> .nav-bar-menu-options.hlink, .nav-bar-menu-options.drop-down{
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: -6px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;

  &.has-divider {
    border-right: 1px solid #b0bec5;
  }

}

:host >>> .nav-bar-menu-options.hlink:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
:host >>> .fill-remaining-space {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
:host >>> .search-link {
  cursor: pointer;
}

:host >>>.search-input-container{
  position:relative;

  .search-link{
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left:30px;
  }
}

:host >>> .my-input{
  border-left: 1px solid #b0bec5;
  padding: 11px 75px 11px 60px;
  background: transparent;
  outline:none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  &::placeholder {

  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why my `.has-divider` & my nested `.search-link` doesn't work and also why when I place the contents inside a .scss file and use `styleUrls` it doesn't work with the `:host`. Is this expected or a possibly Bug

I would Ideally like to be able to still use the nested scss from and external scss file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>>>` is known to cause issues with SASS. Use instead `/deep/`

Comment: so That solved the issue with reading from the file rather than in line but didn't seem to be able to use the nested styles still...

Comment: Actually it seems to work as expected if I just wrap inside `:host /deep/ { ... }`